# What is needed for a User to be able to get the return value of a Decision Matrix Action in an Integration Procedure?

Tags: permissions, vlocity, omnistudio

We are using vlocity at my current workplace and recently updated to the most recent version and we're running into an issue switching from Calculation Matrices to Decision Matrices.

We've trued  making sure the users have access to vlocity, all of it's apex classes, all of our custom ones, to all the Omnistudio objects, and to the Decision Matrix object as well as all of it's child objects (Decision Matrix Row, etc.) and even changing the Decision Matrix sharing settings to Public Read/Write.

However when our users run through an Omniscript with an Integration Procedure making use of a Decision Matrix it ends up not working because the Decision Matrix isn't actually returning any data even though it works just fine for our admins.

I'm sure there's a permission that we've missed somewhere that relates to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still looking for an answer if someone would be able to help?

Comment: Rules Engine Designer - Try assigning this permission Set